# Is $\mathbb{R}^J$ metrizable for $J$ uncountable?

Tags: general-topology

Example 2 section 21 Munkres' Topology says that an uncountable product of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself is not metrizable. Same book Theorem 43.5 says that if a space $Y$ is complete in the metric $d$ then $Y^J$ (J any indexed set) is complete in the uniform metric corresponding to $d$.

My question is that if we can define a metric (uniform metric in here) on $\mathbb{R}^J$ so how it still is not metrizable?!

Comment: There is a uniform metric on $\mathbb{R}^J$ (indeed, there is at least one metric on any set, namely the discrete metric), but it does not generate the product topology!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, what do you mean by generating the product topology?

Comment: The sets which are open with respect to the uniform metric are not the same as the sets which are open with respect to the product topology (a.k.a. the elements of the product topology).

Comment: $Y^J=\prod\{Y:j\in J\}$. I wonder if Munkres discusses uniformities https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Completeness

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, there are many theorems especially in chapter 5 which makes metrizablity equivalent to some specific spaces so every time by metrizable it refers to the topology defined otherwise product topology?

Comment: @Mirko: He does not.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: The default topology on a product of topological spaces is the product topology; you should assume that it is intended unless another is explicitly specified or clear from the context.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: If $J$ is uncountable, $\Bbb R^J$ is not even first countable.

Comment: @Brian I am clear on all of this, and I don't think I ever claimed otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

The product $\Bbb R^J$ by default has the product topology and in that topology the space is not metrisable when $J$ is uncountable. The uniform metric on that set **only** coincides with the product topology when $J$ is finite (even for countable $J$ they're different: one is separable and the other is not, but then both are metrisable topologies, no problem as a set can have many metrics and thus many different metrisable topologies)

$\Bbb R^J$ is called metrisable iff the product topology coincides with the topology induced by some metric and this holds iff $J$ is at most countable (the uniform metric only works for the finite case; Munkres also gives the correct metric for the countable case in another theorem).